# NoClassDefFoundError android.telephony.SubscriptionManager

Tags: android

I have this error when using it on pre-lollipop devices

Is there anyway to use `android.telephony.SubscriptionManager` on pre-lollipop devices?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.telephony.SubscriptionManager
        at naviramyle.stkplus.utils.SendSMS.init(SendSMS.java:40)
        at naviramyle.stkplus.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:95)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you can't I guess as it is added in API Level 22 and  no backward compatibility class.